# What's the phrase to describe this situation/attitude?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-request

Let's say the attitude of being extremely skeptical of someone? Like if my boss looses confidence in me if I make a really small error after doing 99% things correctly. Let's say I made an MS-excel workbook with all the calculations/formulas and I missed a something as trivial as adjusting width of one of the columns in the file, no matter how good/dynamic/elegant use of formulas. I am looking for a good phrase to ridicule the boss's attitude. I can think of 'trust issues' for one.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure there is a single phrase for what you describe, but we can describe aspects of the behavior.

To "nit-pick" means to focus on small mistakes rather than the value of the overall product.

> I wrote this beautiful ten-page report with charts and graphs, accurately detailing our sales increases over the last quarter, but my boss started **nit-picking** about how the width of the margins was all wrong.

A boss who likes to control the employees' performance, instead of giving them autonomy to do a job is called a "micro-manager".

> I once went to work for this guy who was such a **micro-manager** he even started to criticize how often I took bathroom breaks.

"Narrow-minded" and "pedantic" are also possibilities to negatively describe someone who is overly focused on trivia.

The overall way you interact with the people at your work can be called your "working relationship":

> I spent days putting this report together. If my boss can't see the value in it, then I can't see us having a **healthy working relationship** going forward.

This is more neutral, and the kind of thing you'd say to someone in Human Resources when requesting a transfer, or to a potential new employer, "We didn't have a good working relationship."